# Run command 'node filename.js' inside a Docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I need to run a file js inside a Docker container every day at midnight.

Here's my file midnight.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

docker exec -it hash_app bash

node midnight.js
```

Docker exec works fine. But the command 'node midnight.js' doesn't work.

How can I execute midnight.js inside a docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`-c`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) to send commands as string :

```
docker exec -it hash_app bash -c "node midnight.js"
```

Assuming your file is located in `/midnight.js` otherwise :

```
docker exec -it hash_app bash -c "cd /path/to/dir;node midnight.js"
```